# Sort Magento configurable products based on quantity in list page

Tags: magento, configurable-product

How to sort configurable product based on quantity in list page? Currently my default sort order is 'Position' which is assigned in catalog product list. Now i want to change the default sort order based on product quantity.

Can anybody help me on this?